# Creating an mySQL view that sums specific column from another table based on a flag?

Tags: mysql

SQLFiddle Link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c29c/1

I have a table for client information such as IDs, first name, last name, etc.  Then I have a second table that contains orders they have placed.  There are 2 types of orders, a regular order, and a custom order.  Then there is a column for each type of order's total.

This is what the client table looks like

```
[Clients table]
ID - auto incrementing integer
fname - firstname
lname - lastname
```

This is what the order table looks like

```
[Orders table]
orderID - auto incrementing integer
client_ID - fk to Client table
complete - 1 if order is completed, 0 if order is not completed
custom_order - 1 if a custom order, 0 if not a custom order
total - total balance for non custom orders
custom_total - total balance for custom orders
```

I'm trying to create a view that will contain a clientID column, and the totals of all the completed custom order and regular order balances summed together.

So for example if a client with the ID of 599 has 2 completed orders in the Order table, a custom order with a custom_total of $25.05, and a regular order with a total of $5, then in the view it should show the clientID of 599, and a total order count of 2, and a total order balance of $30.05.

Here is what I have so far for the view declaration.  Of course it isn't working.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW client_order_totals AS
SELECT
    c.ID,
    c.fname,
    c.lname,
    CASE
        WHEN o.custom_order = 1 AND o.complete = 1
            THEN o.custom_total
        WHEN o.custom_order = 0 AND o.complete = 1
            THEN o.total
        ELSE 0
    END AS totals,
    SUM(totals) AS realtotal, --This line doesn't work.
    COUNT(*) AS ordercount --This doesn't work either.
FROM Clients c
LEFT JOIN Orders o ON c.ID = o.client_ID
GROUP BY c.ID
```

The following is a full example of what should happen

```
[Clients table]
ID  fname   lname
29, George, Smith
30, Jerree, Leris

[Orders table]
orderID client_ID  complete  custom_order  total  custom_total
      1,       29,        1,            1,     0,           10
      2,       29,        1,            0,     3,            0
      3,       29,        0,            0,     6,           30
      4,       30,        0,            1,     7,            5
```

As a result, the new client_order_totals view should look like the following

```
[client_order_totals view]
ID  fname   lname  ordercount  ordertotal
29  George  Smith           2          13
30  Jerree  Leris           0           0
```

Thank you!

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c29c/1 Here is the sqlfiddle link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT c.*
     , SUM(o.complete=1)
     , SUM(CASE WHEN o.complete=1 THEN total + custom_total ELSE 0 END) ttl
  FROM clients c
  JOIN orders o
    ON o.client_id = c.id
 GROUP
    BY c.id;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0bbf/4

or something like that

Comment: Thanks Strawberry!  I modified it a little so it worked the way it should.

    DROP VIEW IF EXISTS client_order_totals;
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW client_order_totals AS
    SELECT
        c.*
        SUM(o.complete=1) AS count,
        SUM(
            CASE
                WHEN o.complete=1 AND o.custom_order=0
                    THEN total
                WHEN o.complete=1 AND o.custom_order=1
                    THEN custom_total
                ELSE 0
            END
        ) ordertotal
    FROM Clients c
    JOIN Orders o ON o.client_ID = c.ID
    GROUP BY c.ID

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no need for if statements:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW client_order_totals AS
select a.ID, a.fname, a.lname, sum(a.complete) ordercount, sum(a.complete*(a.total+a.custom_total)) ordertotal
from Clients a
join Orders b on a.ID = b.client_ID
group by a.ID;
```